# Não acessar imagem pela url

Tags: php, css, css3

Como faço para passar uma imagem para o componente *img* sem que o usuário possa copiar a *url* da imagem e  acessar o arquivo pelo navegador?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<img src="https://meusite.com.br/assets/upload/galeria/89483adsd4r49939304.png"/>
<img src="<?php echo $url?>assets/upload/galeria/<?php echo $foto->imagem?>"/>
```

Comment: Se o navegador pode abrir a imagem signficia que o usuário também pode, mesmo que você a codifique o usuário também poderá pegar o código codificado e decoficarlo, se você quiser esconder o endereço original da imagem, poderia tentar htaccess;

Comment: você pode abrir o arquivo e apresentar o base64 como `data:url` isso não vai impedir que o uuário copie a imagem... mas não vai expor seu endereço no servidor que no caso não precisa nem estar na estrutura acessível ao client.

Comment: Por qual motivo você deseja ocultar a **url** do `src` para o usuário?

Comment: Você esta querendo que o usuário não possa acessar a pasta e ver todos os arquivos nela ? (*directory browsing*)

Comment: @IcaroMartins isso mesmo

Comment: Você esta usando `apache2` ?

Comment: @IcaroMartins estou sim utilizando o apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desabilitando o **Directory browsing** do **apache2**, você pode utilizar uma das opções abaixo.

#### Opção 1: Via comando:

```
a2dismod autoindex
```

Apos isso restarte o `apache2`

```
/etc/init.d/apache restart
```

---

#### Opção 2: Editando o arquivo de configuração do apache

<sub>**Localização antiga:** Ache seu arquivo *httpd.conf* normalmente no path */etc/apache/httpd.conf* *(fonte dessa informação parece esta desatualizada)*</sub>

**Localização mais recente:** Procure o arquivo de configuração do site, por padrão é `000-default.conf` e fica no path `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Procure por uma linha parecida com a mostrada abaixo

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Remova o texto `Indexes` como mostrado abaixo
<sup>(se não tiver um dos itens mostrado não é necessário adicionar, o importante aqui e você tirar o *Indexes*)</sup>

```
Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Apos isso restarte o `apache2`

```
/etc/init.d/apache restart
```

---

#### Opção 3: apenas em um diretório especifico

Outra método é você criar um arquivo `.htaccess` dentro da pasta que você quer desabilitar essa feature e colocar como conteúdo

```
Options -Indexes
```

---

#### Opção 4: Criar um arquivo `index.php` ou `index.html`

Ao colocar um arquivo index.php ou index.html na pasta quando o usuário tentar acessar a pasta vai cair dentro da index que você criou e não na index automática do apache.

---

**[NOTA]:** No caso de querer esconder o path da imagem você pode criar um arquivo [php](/questions/tagged/php) para agir como uma imagem, basta carregar os dados da imagem para uma variável (como por exemplo usando a função `file_get_contents('imagem.png')`) e usar um dos exemplos nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372327/3774)

Fontes: [stackoverflow - EN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530372/2456894)

Comment: Mas ele não queria ocultar o endereço da imagem do `src=""` ?

Comment: Acho que ele não soube se expressar, ai eu perguntei no [comentário da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372110/n%C3%A3o-acessar-imagem-pela-url/372115?noredirect=1#comment740130_372110).

Comment: @IcaroMartins deu certo com a **Opção 2**. Apenas com .htaccess resolveu o problema. Sobre a pergunta eu fiz menos técnica, porque gostaria de saber quais seria as opções que poderia ter para resolver o problema e foi exatamente o que você respondeu. Agradeço!