# Problema ao exibir imagem entre tags html

Tags: php, html, mysql, aplicação-web

Estou tentando exibir em um template imagens que são salvos em um banco de dados, a inserção e a busca da imagem são feitas corretamente, a exibição também, porém até certo ponto, pois quando eu tento exibir a imagem entre tags html  a tela fica toda preta com a imagem no centro como se não tivesse sido encontrada, por exemplo:

```
<?php 
require_once '../customers/functions.php';
require_once(DBAPI);

$database =open_database();

$sql = "SELECT id, imagem FROM gema_vitrine WHERE id = 4";
$query = $database->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
$foto = $result['imagem'];
Header( "Content-type: image/gif");
?>
<div>
    <?php echo $foto; ?>
</div>
```

Da maneira que o código esta acima, a página fica assim: http://prntscr.com/n4xlrj

Agora se eu remover a tag html a imagem é exibida corretamente.

De que maneira eu posso corrigir isso para que eu possa exibir as imagens vindas do banco em um template html organizado da forma que eu quero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que você explicou, imagino que sua variável `$result['imagem']` possui o 'binário' da imagem, para fazer uma comparação rápida seria como se você estive-se executado um `file_get_contents('minhaimagem.gif')` e jogando para essa variável, por isso funciona quando você coloca:

```
Header( "Content-type: image/gif");
echo $foto;   // <- $foto é equivalente ao dado de um file_get_contents('minhaimagem.gif')
```

**Ou seja o seu arquivo [php](/questions/tagged/php) esta fazendo o papel de um arquivo com o nome terminado em `.gif`**. Dito isso agora você já deve esta entendendo que quando você adiciona a tag `div`, ou qualquer outra coisa a esse dado 'binário' você esta transformando sua imagem em uma **imagem corrompida** como mostrado abaixo:

```
Header( "Content-type: image/gif");
echo "<div>$foto</div>";
```

<sup>Isso é a mesma coisa que você abrir uma imagem como arquivo de texto, escrever algo, salvar e depois tentar abri-la como imagem.</sup>

---

### Solução 1

Você pode criar um outro arquivo e nele fazer adicionar a tag `img` passando como `src` o nome do arquivo que esta fazendo o papel de imagem.
Exemplo:

Imaginando que esse arquivo se chama `minha_imagem.php`

```
Header( "Content-type: image/gif");
echo $foto;
```

Cria um novo arquivo chamado `pagina.php` ou `pagina.html` e adicione o seguinte código:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img src='minha_imagem.php'/>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Solução 2

Fazer uma função que pega o 'binário' da imagem e transforma em um `dataURI`

```
function dataURI( $bin )
{
    return 'data: image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $bin );
    // ^               ^
    // |   Estou imaginando que seja um gif
    // Vai gerar algo como "data: image/gif;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAg...+LJGj21jxe//9k="
    //                                                                ^
    //                       Isso é uma string longa eu removi parte aqui
    //                       essa string pode ser utilizada como 'src' de uma imagem
}
```

<sup>Se você tiver o nome do arquivo da imagem você pode utilizar uma função como a [`mime_content_type ( $nome_do_arquivo )`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mime-content-type.php) para pegar essa informação `image/gif`</sup>

E usar ela em sua pagina como mostrado no exemplo:

```
require_once '../customers/functions.php';
require_once(DBAPI);

$database =open_database();

$sql = "SELECT id, imagem FROM gema_vitrine WHERE id = 4";
$query = $database->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
$foto = $result['imagem'];

// Header( "Content-type: image/gif");

function dataURI( $bin )
{
    return 'data: image/gif;base64,'.base64_encode( $bin );
}

$foto = dataURI($foto);

echo "<div> <img src='$foto'/> </div>";
```

Comment: Usei a primeira solução e funcionou, e imagino que vá casar bem com o que pretendo fazer, muito obrigado!